# Assignment to temporary, GCC 9.3 bug or ill formed code/UB?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, undefined-behavior

This question is very short and I apologize for the lack of detail I'm running short on time.

I ran into what seems like a bug to me. You can find the code here: https://godbolt.org/z/eWMbb7qrK .
This code compiles on clang since at least version 8. On gcc however, it does not compile before 10.1 (I only tested compilers available on God bolt).

So while it has been fixed in recent versions, I'd like to know if there is a solution to make this code work or "old" compilers, with as small a change as possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
 public:
  constexpr A() : i_{} {}
  constexpr A(const A&) = default;
  template <int i>
  constexpr A(const char (&the_data)[i]) : i_{i} {}

  int i_;
};

int main() {
  {
    A a{"aze"};
    std::cout << a.i_ << '\n';
  }
  {
    A a{A{"aze"}};
    std::cout << a.i_ << '\n';
  }
  {
    A a{};
    a = A{"aze"};
    std::cout << a.i_ << '\n';
  }
  {
    static_assert((A{} = A{"aze"}).i_ == 4, "");
    std::cout << (A{} = A{"aze"}).i_ << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Reduced the bug on gcc-9.4 to `template<int n> struct int_t { static constexpr int value = n; };` followed by `int_t<(A{} = A{"aze"}).i_>::value` being `0`: https://godbolt.org/z/q44zs7o6b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaulted constexpr assignment operator looks faulty on gcc-9.4 and prior. Define it yourself.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  constexpr A() : i_{} {}
  constexpr A(const A&) = default;
  template <int i>
  constexpr A(const char (&the_data)[i]) : i_{i} {}
  constexpr A& operator=(A const& other)
  { i_ = other.i_; return *this; }

  int i_;
};


int main() {
  {
    static_assert((A{} = A{"aze"}).i_ == 4, "");
  }
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/hGjEK37Yo

Comment: related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93975

Comment: As a matter of fact, clang and gcc trunk might also be incorrect. The default assignment operator for `A` should _not_ be `constexpr` as it is not  a litteral-type.

Comment: Indeed, a warning should be shown at least when the pedantic flag is set

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why exactly it is failing, but you can change

```
(A{} = A{"aze"}).i_
```

to be

```
A{"aze"}.i_
```

and it compiles in the older versions: [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/K68MdMTEM)

Comment: Indeed, I just wanted to know if it was a bug or not, seems like it is.